# It is possible to modify the system settings programmatically in a IOS app

Tags: ios

As the title describes, I'm wondering if it is possible to modify the settings such as restrictions, accessibility within an app by running code, does apple provide such API to achieve this?

Comment: Not possible to use apple private api.

Comment: Nope, the best you can do is to open the settings app at a desired section.

Comment: @zibo As per my knowledge, Apple does not allow to change hardware settings programmatically.

Comment: No, its not possible. Apple does not allow to modify setting programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible.

You can make a custom alert with explanations what user should do in settings and add and action button to open the Settings app:

```
func openSettings(_ completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    guard let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
        return
    }
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, completionHandler: completion)

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can. Now at least.

using UserDefaults.standard.setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)

Just use the same key as you use in your plist.